# Spring boot maven executable jar not running with Double click

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Created a maven jar of a simple spring boot application.
If I try and execute the jar file from the command line using java -jar x.jar and it runs ok, even see all the traces of spring boot..booting up..

If try to execute it just by double clicking it with the mouse, it wont run. A command window pops up for a milli second and vanishes and if I try to get to an exposed endpoint (HTTP Rest - Get)..site cant be reached error..

The project is a sample Eureka server, so contains cloud dependencies..

Any ideas what could be the problem, is it just some environment setting?!

Regards,

From the POM:

```
    <groupId>example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServiceDiscovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
.
.
.
.
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
.
.
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Basic Spring Eureka example, virtually no code except:

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Any code sample? Is jar file executable? Which spring boot version? Which operating system?

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

> To create a ‘fully executable’ jar with Maven, use the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> The following example shows the equivalent Gradle configuration:

```
bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
```

> You can then run your application by typing ./my-application.jar (where my-application is the name of your artifact). The directory containing the jar is used as your application’s working directory.

Comment: I tried that option didnt work, the documentation does say use this to make it fully executable, but also says for *nix machines, I assume Unix based OS then!

Comment: Ok, thanks, the link has quite a bit of information..and my operating system is Win.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem at all

Doubble click on **jar** fie and executing by command are not same

```
java -jar x.jar
```

Either execute from eclipse or from command prompt.
Else change Windows(operating system) setting or change **execution setting** in maven config  to execute from command prompt

Comment: I just wanted to say that, I've tried to execute one way and it worked, obviously still doesnt mean that all the env settings on the machine are correct, was just stating as a piece of info